# Where can I get good explanations of all thymeleaf out of the box processors?

Tags: java, spring, view, templating, thymeleaf

There are a couple mentioned in the documentation but looking through the api,  there are tons more processors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current JavaDoc is indeed lacking in completeness. I find myself in the same situation where I am constantly searching for which abstract processor is the best to use, even though the names of the processors are pretty straight forward.

Currently the only way to exactly know what a processor does and how to use them is to open the source code.